# Where do you set up email settings in teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

I am VERY new with teamcity so please bear with me

I set up an email notifier to let me know when a build has failed, but TeamCity is reporting the following error:

> Failed to send email notification via
>   SMTP server mail, due to error:
>   Unknown SMTP host: mail; nested
>   exception is:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: mail

For the life of me, I cannot find where to configure the mail server settings.  I don't even want it to use an SMTP server, but I don't see any options for this anywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Option                 Description 
------                 ----------
SMTP host              Specify the SMTP host name.
SMTP port              Specify the SMTP port number.
Send messages from     Specify the email address, from which notification messages will be sent to the user.
SMTP login             Specify the SMTP login name, if any.
SMTP password          Specify the SMTP password.
Use TLS (SSL)          Select this option to secure your SMTP connection with TLS.
                       (This feature is only available in TeamCity 3.1+)
Test connection        Click this button to establish a connection with the specified SMTP host.
Save                   Click this button to save changes and close the page.
```

source: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD3/Email+and+Jabber+Notifier+Settings

Comment: aha!  Can I have it not use an email server?

Comment: If you want it to email you when a build has failed, there's probably not any good way to get around having one.

Comment: Man, thats a lot of effort for what is basically a server running on my own machine and for my own benefit.

Comment: set it to your loopback address if smtp is running locally 127.0.0.1

Comment: We avoided setting up our own email server for TeamCity by using the SMTP service provided as part of Gmail / GoogleApps. See http://www.activecollab.com/forums/topic/3552/

Comment: @dthrasher yeah, I thought of that, but both setting up a new gmail account just for this and using my own are distasteful options. Ill do it later I guess when I'm setting this up for real.

Answer (score 10):

You can configure your email settings under Administration - Server Configuration - Email Notifier..

Answer (score 3):

Sumeru's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/825701/86627) describes the mail account you need to set in order for TeamCity to be able to send email notifications.  The actual notifications   are sent on a per-user base.  Each user can define the notificatinos they wish to receive.  In teamCity Professional 7x You can do this under: 
Username/My Settings & tools/Watched Builds and Notifications/Email Notifier